# Rs. 100 have/has been returned to your child

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> 1. Rs. 100 **have been** returned to your child.
> 2. Rs. 100 **has been** returned to your child.

Which one of the above sentences is correct and why?

Comment: More context is needed. What is "Rs 100"? Does it represent one or several elements?

Comment: Oops – I voted to close this as a duplicate, but when I read it more carefully, I realized this might be an example of a measure expression with singular override.  I'll reopen the post for now.

Comment: Currency is usually a mass noun, so you'd say "$100 has been returned to your child", but there are cases where we can treat it as a count noun, especially if we're talking about individual units of physical currency, as in "100 dollar[ bill]s have been returned to your child".

Answer (score -2):

A) Rs 100 have been returned to your child

100 denotes multiple rupees i.e. plural and hence have been should be used.
If it was Rs.1, the sentence would have been Rs.1 has been returned to your child.